Finding ratio of lengths in a figure with many circles
Question: Let $\triangle TBD$ be a triangle with $TB = 6$, $BD = 8$, and $DT = 7$. Let $I$ be the incenter of $\triangle TBD$, and let $TI$ intersect the circumcircle of $\triangle TBD$ at $M \neq T$. Define $Y = TB \cap MD$ and $X = TD \cap MB$. The circumcircles of $\triangle YBM$ and $\triangle XDM$ meet at $Z \neq M$. Compute the ratio of the areas of $\triangle YBZ$ and $\triangle XDZ$.

Using Miquel and Steiner’s quadrilateral theorem (statement of theorem), quadrilaterals $TYZD$ and $TBXZ$ are cyclic. From this, we can deduce the following:
$$\angle TDZ+\angle ZYB=\angle TDZ+\angle ZDX=180^{\circ} \implies \angle ZYB=\angle ZDX$$
$$\angle YBZ+\angle TBZ=\angle DXZ+\angle TBZ=180^{\circ} \implies\angle YBZ=\angle DXZ$$
Therefore, $\angle YBZ \sim \triangle DXZ$, meaning $$\frac{[\triangle YBZ]}{[\triangle XDZ]}=\left(\frac{YZ}{DZ} \right)^2$$ However, I am unsure how to (nicely) find $\frac{YZ}{DZ}$ without an awful trig bash.

FYI: Via a Mathematica-assisted coordinate bash (and confirmed with a GeoGebra sketch), I found that
$$\frac{|YZ|}{|DZ|}=\frac{d (d (b + d) - t^2)}{b (b (b + d) - t^2)} = \frac{\cos\frac12(B+3D)}{\cos\frac12(3B+D)}$$
When $b=7$, $d=6$, $t=8$, this ratio is $4/9$.

Update: This is 2023 PUMaC Team Round Question 13. Solution attached in comments.

The simplest way to conquer the situation is maybe to use barycentric coordinates. Here is a short reference due to Max Schindler and Evan Chen.

We are in the following situation, to use the standard notations:


In our case, $a,b,c$ are respectively $8,7,6$, but we insert these values only at the end of computations. We use $(x,y,z)$ as a notation for normed barycentric coordinates of a point $P$, i.e. $x+y+z=1$, so $P=xA+yB+zC$ is the point - plotting either affixes (complex numbers) or cartesian coordinates in the places of $A,B,C;P$. But we will never do so.
We identify $P$ with the vector $(x,y,z)$ in $\Bbb R^3$.
For unnormed coordinates, the notation $P=[x:y:z]$ means that one has to norm, i.e. $P=\frac 1{x+y+z}(x,y,z)=\left(\ \frac x{x+y+z},\ \frac x{x+y+z},\ \frac x{x+y+z}\ \right)$.
Most relations and equations can be stated conveniently using unnormed coordinates (since there is often a homogenity in there).
Recall the known values $A=(1,0,0)$, $b=(0,1,0)$, $C=(0,0,1)$; $I=[a:b:c]$.
We start the computations, no detail is omitted.


The point $M$ is the intersection of the circumcircle of equation, Corollary 9 in loc cit., $0=a^2yz+b^2zx+c^2xy$ with the line through $A=(1,0,0)$ and $I=[a:b:c]$, i.e. with the line having the equation $0=
\begin{vmatrix}x&y&z\\1&0&0\\a&b&c\end{vmatrix}$, i.e. $y/b=z/c$. So $M=[?:b:c]$, and plugging this into the circumcircle equation we get:
$$
M=[\ -a^2\ :\ b(b+c)\ :\ c(b+c)\ ]
=\frac 1{b(b+c)-a^2}(\ -a^2\ ,\ b(b+c)\ ,\ c(b+c)\ )\ .
$$
The point $Y$ is the intersection of $AB$ (equation $z=0$) with the line $CM$ of equation
$0=
\begin{vmatrix}x&y&z\\0&0&1\\-a^2&b(b+c)&c(b+c)\end{vmatrix}$,
so taking the version of $M$ with a removed $z$-component gives $Y$,
$$
Y=
[\ -a^2\ :\ b(b+c)\ :\ 0\ ]
=\frac 1{b(b+c)-a^2}(-a^2\ ,\ b(b+c)\ ,\ 0\ )
\ .
$$
Similarly, the point $X$ is obtained by switching $b,c$, and the $y,z$ components:
$$
X=
[\ -a^2\ :\ 0\ :\ c(b+c)\ ]
=\frac 1{c(b+c)-a^2}(-a^2\ ,\ 0\ ,\ c(b+c)\ )
\ .
$$
In order to compute the length of $YB$ we compute the displacement vector
$$
\overrightarrow{YB}
=B-Y
=(0,1,0)-\frac 1{b(b+c)-a^2}(-a^2\ ,\ b(b+c)\ ,\ 0\ )
=\frac {a^2}{b(b+c)-a^2}(1,-1,0)\ .
$$
Let $(x,y,z)$ be the components of the last vector. In our case $z=0$.
The distance formula, Theorem 7 from loc. cit., gives us for $|BY|^2$ the formula $-a^2yz-b^2zx-c^2xy$, so the only term $-c^2xy$ without $z$ survives, and we get
$$
|BY|=\frac{ca^2}{|b(b+c)-a^2|}\ .
$$
Its value is explicitly $128/9$.
Similarly,
$$
|CX|=\frac{ba^2}{|c(b+c)-a^2|}\ .
$$
Its value is explicitly $32 = 128/4$.
The wanted proportion of areas is thus the square $16/81$ of
$$\frac{|BY|}{|CX|}
=\frac{128/9}{128/4}=\frac 49\ .
$$
$\square$


By law of sines on triangles $\triangle YBD$ and $\triangle XDB$, we have $\frac{YB}{\sin\tfrac T2}=\frac{8}{\sin Y}$ and $\frac{XD}{\sin\tfrac T2}=\frac{8}{\sin X}$. Hence,
$$\frac{YB}{XD}=\frac{\sin(D-\tfrac T2)}{\sin(B-\tfrac T2)}=\frac49$$
by a straight forward calculation.

The easier ratio to find is $\overline{BY} : \overline{DX}$. Using the Law of Sines on $BMY$ and $DMX$, the length of $BY$ is
$$
\overline{BM} \cdot \frac{\sin \angle BMY}{\sin \angle BYM},
$$
and  the length of $DX$ is
$$
\overline{DM} \cdot \frac{\sin \angle DMX}{\sin \angle DXM}.
$$
Note that $\overline{BM} = \overline{DM}$ and $\angle BMY = \angle DMX$, so the ratio is just
$$\overline{BY} : \overline{DX} = \sin \angle DXM : \sin \angle BYM.$$
Looking at circle $TDMB$, we have $\angle DXM = \angle D - \frac12 \angle T$ and $\angle BYM = \angle B - \frac12 \angle T$.
From here, you should be able to use the Law of Cosines and the half angle formula to calculate the desired ratio.
Note: I think this is the solution @Bob Dobbs used as well.

Here is the solution that I was referring to in my comment:

